# Hava a java panel load another jpanel

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm using netbeans to create a GUI application. I've made a main form with a panel that I want other jPanels I make to be placed in. It seems like this should be simple to do seeing as the create new context menu allows me to make plain java panels. I've made all the variables public on the new frame also.

EDIT:

I have a separate class extending the jPanel that is public, I'm trying to load it into a panel I have on the main GUI using the following code:

```
private void qmcatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    qmcat jQmcat = new qmcat(); 
    jQmcat.setVisible(true); 
    jPanel.add(jQmcat); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have now?

Comment: I've put your (misformatted) code from the comment into the question; please delete your comment.  For future, there is a small edit hyperlink under you question which you can use to add further information.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong method, it is .add(name, then component) , this is sad.